# c# online scheduling application

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

I would like to find some tool that would let me run scheduled c# job online, for example every night at 2 am.
I need to run some scripts every day, but I don't want to do it manually, also and I don't always have my computer around.

Does anyone know any tool like this?

BR

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a .exe that create HTTP request. Use Windows Task Scheduler to schedule that .exe to run  on a schedule.